# Create DateTime Object in 24 Hour Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am creating a DateTime object with this constructor

```
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond);
```

but the issue is the Hour Values I am having are in 24 hour format.
so When I do this

```
DateTime dTime = new DateTime(2015, 2, 16, 30, 25, 34);
```

I get an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: 2015 Feb 16th 30 hours, 25 minutes, 34 seconds.

Comment: How can `30` be the hour part in `DateTime`, ? DateTime itself doesn't have any format associated with it, format is just for displaying

Comment: Nothing more to say really ... `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, and you're trying to feed the constructor an argument with a value of 30, when it is expecting something in the range of 0 to 23. That sounds very `out of range`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no `30` as a day hour in Gregorian calender [*or any calender as far as I know*](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/table6.html).

As pointed from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> hour Type: System.Int32
>
> The hours (**0** through **23**).

This has nothing relevant with [24 hour format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock). A format *only* applies when you try to get string representation of your `DateTime`.